# Laravel not displaying special UTF8 characters on 'public' server

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have just started working with Laravel, having worked with PHP & MySQL for a few years now, and have just come across a problem i can't seem to solve.

I have a new shop which i have just built in Laravel, sitting on my development server, connected to my development database.

Also I have a CMS system, built in my own framework, on my public server, connected to the public database.

And now i have just uploaded my Laravel shop front end to my public server, connected to the public database.

Both the developmebnt front end (Laravel) and public CMS (my framework) work fine, but the public front end (laravel) won't display special characters:

```
5” x 7” magnetic frame
```

Displays as:

```
5â€ x 7â€ magnetic frame
```

But I'm at a loss, there are no differences between the development and public system, except the environment variables holding the database name, host, username and pass.
The public CMS system displays the same characters fine too, so therefore the database must be ok too. (I just straight copied the databse from development to live too.)

Here is the connection array:

```
'connections' => array(

    'Default' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => $_ENV['CONN']['DB HOST'],
        'database'  => $_ENV['CONN']['DB DBSE'],
        'username'  => $_ENV['CONN']['DB USER'],
        'password'  => $_ENV['CONN']['DB PASS'],
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),

),
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be most welcome!

Comment: Have you set the headers on the public site to use utf-8? Also are you 100% sure your database on live is UTF8? You may be running code through html entities on the cms.

Comment: Obligatory http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: As above - make sure it's UTF8 EVERYWHERE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your HTML

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
```

It may be defaulting to utf-8 on your local environment if it's not specified and for some reason or another, not in the production environment.

Comment: <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
Is already in my HTML head